# A probability counterexample for the measure $Q(A) = \int_{\Omega} X \mathbb{1}_A \mathbb{1}_B \ \text{d} \mathbb{P}$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, $B \in \mathcal{A}$ and $X : \Omega \to (0,\infty)$ an integrable random variable. Define $$Q :  \mathcal{A} \to [0,\infty) \quad \text{such that} \quad Q(A) = \int_{\Omega} X \mathbb{1}_A \mathbb{1}_B \ \text{d} \mathbb{P}$$

I've shown that $Q$ defines a measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$ by Beppo Levi (exchanging integral and sum). Then I have shown that for any random variable $Y \geq 0$, we have $$\int_{\Omega} Y \ \text{d} Q = \int_{\Omega} XY \mathbb{1}_B \ \text{d} \mathbb{P}$$ by first showing that it's true for $Y = \mathbb{1}_A$ then it's true by linearity for any simple function $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \alpha_k\mathbb{1}_{A_k}$ and finally true  by MCT for a non-negative random variable that can be approximated by simple functions $\varphi_{n} \uparrow Y$.

Assuming now that $\int_{\Omega} X \ \text{d} \mathbb{P} = 1$, does it follow that $Q$ is a probability measure, i.e $Q(\Omega) = 1$? I don't think so, since $Q(\Omega) = \int_{B} X \ \text{d} \mathbb{P} \leq \int_{\Omega} X \ \text{d} \mathbb{P} = 1$ but can't come up with a counterexample. Any help on what to consider? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take $X=1$. Then $\int XdP=1$ but $Q(\Omega)=P(B)$ which may be less than $1$.

For a specific counter-example take $\Omega=(0,1)$, $P=$ Lebesgue measure $B=(0,\frac 1 2)$ and $X=1$.

Comment: but don't I need to specifiy $B$ as well, so also define $\Omega$ and $\mathbb{P}$, in order to contrust the counterexample?

Comment: @9Sp I have added a specific example where $Q(\Omega)=\frac 1 2 $.

Comment: :D oh sure, I feel silly now for not thinking to just take $(0,1)$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$ with lebesgue measure ! thanks a lot.